# I don't understand the reason for the alignment of the char buffer[] with an object of type X in the code below

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

Stroustrup in his new book in page 151 shows the following example of the use of the type specifier `alignas`:

> Sometimes, we have to use alignment in a declaration, where an
>   expression, such as alignof(x+y) is not allowed. Instead, we can use
>   the type specifier  alignas: alignas(T) means "align just like a T."
>   For example , we can set aside uninitialized storage for some type X
>   like this:

```
void user(const vector<X>& vx)
{
    constexpr int bufmax = 1024;
    alignas(X) char buffer[bufmax];    // unitialized
    const int max = min(vx.size(), bufmax/sizeof(X));
    unitialized_copy(vx.begin(), vx.begin() + max, buffer);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @sjdowling This seems to be a reasonable explanation. I'll accept that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer is of type `char` and so will be aligned for `char` but he actually wants to store `X` in it and `X` may require a different alignment to `char` and so the `alignas` specifier allows him to ensure it is correctly aligned for `X` objects.